# Change featured image when changing viewport

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have a featured image linked to my page. In my page template, I have:

```
<?php 
 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
   the_post_thumbnail();
  }
?>
```

I want that the featured image changes when I reduce the size of the viewport.

`"fi-large.png"` for larger screens,
`"fi-small.png"` for smaller screens,...

Comment: You cannot do this in PHP. (Well, technically you can, but it requires a lot of work and probably makes no sense.) Have you tried outputting both in PHP and then displaying either one via a custom CSS rule?

Comment: It is probably the best solution but it requires to go into the code to change the source. I wanted something that can be managed in the admin panel.

Comment: You need code to do this, this cannot be done via the admin panel alone.